# Where to connect C-wire on old furnace (diagram attached)

Tags: wiring, hvac, furnace, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I've got an old steam furnace and would like to add a common wire.  The wire is already ran, I just have no idea where to connect it.

I thought it would go to TR but that didn't work.  Thanks in advance, much appreciated!

[image: Current Wiring Diagram]

[image: Picture of the current wires]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more closely I'm thinking the way everything is currently wired it isn't possible to get a complete circuit for the C-wire.  I made a proposed diagram that makes a little more sense to me, but I am definitely no expert so I'm looking for advice.  Would this work?

[image]

I tried to edit the original question but it wouldn't let me post an additional photo.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked, with one slight modification.  The wires RH and W going into the thermostat are reversed in the diagram.  the C wire relies on the RH wire to complete the circuit, not W.

Answer (score 0):

Found this link [here](https://xtronics.com/wiki/Thermostat_signals_and_wiring.html) stating that the blue C wire is the 24V AC transformer Neutral wire, hope this is of some use to you.

Comment: Thank you, that was very useful actually.  It helped me figure out the path the C wire takes to complete it's circuit.